# How to exclude values that contain a number at the end in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Example address: 1900 PRIVATE RD 504

I want to exclude addresses that have numbers at the end of it because it indicates an apartment. I am looking for addresses that are not apartments in my SQL.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: There are many streets that are numbers. Routes especially. For example, 2222 W Route  12. Also, depending on what you mean by "apartment", I lived in a condo that had a numeric unit number.

Comment: @Nikki9696 By apartment I meant secondary units so I want single family homes only. And you make a good point about the route :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this depends on the database,  However, most databases support the `right()` string function, so a simple method is:

```
where right(address, 1) not between '0' and '9'
```

Note:  Not all apartment addresses end in a number.  For instance, the apartment I am sitting in now is unit 12C-S.